# How to exchange a string with an index during C preprocess

Tags: c, string, indexing, c-preprocessor

I have in several C-sources trace statements, like

```
TRACE(23, "abc"); 
TRACE(24, "def");
```

The numbers 23 and 24 are identifiers counted out of an automatically generated list containing in each line one string

```
...
"abc"
"def"
...
```

"abc" is in line 23 and so I write 23 in the appropriate trace statement.

The preprocessor generates me this wanted output

```
trace(23);
trace(24);
```

I think it should be possible to automate it in that way that I only write

```
TRACE("abc"); 
TRACE("def");
```

During C preprocessing i want to exchange the strings with the appropriate line number of my generated file automatically, so that I get in the preprocessor output

```
trace(23);
trace(24);
```

I can write a function which returns me the line number 23 for the string "abc" but I need to activate it during the preprocessing process. Are there any preprocessor hooks or other ideas?

Comment: Please elaborate. "I have sources", please show examples. "a generated file" please show. "I want to ...", please show some desired output for the sample input. Also please describe what you tried, in order to demonstrate some own research effort. Maybe you can show something you did which is kind of but not copmletely what you want. Generally try to avoid the impression "here are requirements, please give code".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?  Could it be something that the compiler macro `__LINE__` or maybe `__FILE__` can help with?

Comment: It is a software tracer for very small embedded systems. The trace strings are not going into the target. They are loaded dynamically by a PC tool. The target sends a 23 and the host knows it is "abc". I know `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` but I have no idea how they can help me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

---

The preprocessor supplies the automagic macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` (and a few others) which you can use:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRACE(m) fprintf(stderr, "%s,%d: %s\n", __FILE__ , __LINE__, m)

int main(void)
{
int a;

if(a) TRACE("a");
else TRACE("no");

TRACE("returning");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea now: Let the preprocessor generate this output:

```
trace("abc"); 
trace("def");
```

Than write a tool (i.e. a bash script with awk) exchanging the strings with their line number from the generated list file:

```
...
"abc"
"def"
...
```

And finally let the compiler do his work. I am not really happy with it, because it needs to be adapted for each compiler. Any better idea?